# How can I add SOAP Headers to a WSDL generated Borland C++ Builder 6 application

Tags: c++, authentication, soap, header, c++builder

Using a WSDL that requires a SOAP HEADER for Authentication (fragment below) code that gets generated when creating a web service client via the "WSDL Importer" has no concept of the Authentication Headers and there are no examples in BCB6 C++ Examples/WebServices directories that show how, and nothing on Web that I can find.

Anyone with BCB6 C++ (not Delphi) have an example of adding SOAP Headers to a TRemotable subclass?

```
<s:element name="AuthenticationHeader" type="tns:AuthenticationHeader"/>
<s:complexType name="AuthenticationHeader">
 <s:complexContent mixed="false">
  <s:extension base="tns:UserAuthHeader">
   <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Function" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TimeOutMilliSec" type="s:int"/>
   </s:sequence>
  </s:extension>
 </s:complexContent>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="UserAuthHeader">
 <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="s:string"/>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
 </s:sequence>
 <s:anyAttribute/>
</s:complexType>
```